# jade unexpected token setting attribute in the template

Tags: node.js, express, pug

```
button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right#add-btn(data-userId=#{userId}) Save
```

Any idea why it got error of unexpected token `}`? my userId have something from the controller.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to put `#{ }` around JavaScript code when defining attributes in Jade, that is only [when Jade would expect a text string](http://jade-lang.com/reference/interpolation/).

From the [docs on attributes](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/):

> Tag attributes look similar to html, however their values are just regular JavaScript.

So your example becomes simply:

```
button.btn.btn-primary.pull-right#add-btn(data-userId=userId) Save
```